# Duda en programa en Python para encontrar las páginas web de un archivo fuente y crear una lista de los elementos encontrados

Tags: python, while, buscador

Buen día, estoy aprendiendo a usar Python y en un ejercicio que estoy desarrollando se debe realizar un programa que encuentre todos los url en un archivo de texto (ArchivoPaginaWeb.txt, que es el código fuente de una página web) y con ello generar una lista de lo encontrado, el código que he realizado es el siguiente:

```
def buscasig(pagweb):
    iniciopos=pagweb.find('<a href=')
    if iniciopos==-1:
        return None,0
    iniciocita=pagweb.find('"',iniciopos)
    finposic=pagweb.find('"',iniciocita+1)
    url=pagweb[iniciocita+1:finposic]
    return url,finposic

def urls(pagweb):
    listaurls=[]
    while True:
        url,finposic=buscasig(pagweb)
        if url:
            listaurls.append(url)
            pagweb=pagweb[finposic:]
        else:
            break
    return listaurls

def main():
    with open ('ArchivoPaginaWeb.txt') as archpagweb:
        pagweb=archpagweb.read()
        listaurls=urls(pagweb)
        print("Enlaces encontrados:",listaurls)

main()
```

La idea es obtener una salida tipo lista con diferentes url, parecida a esto:

```
Enlaces encontrados: ['https://www.ejemplos.co/30-ejemplos-de-url/',
'https://1drv.ms/v/s!AkuEHsI016zRhTzzZFGqj0TSOsSh', 'http://www.ejemplos.co/30-ejemplos-deurl']
```

Sin embargo, al momento de ejecutarlo solo me encuentra un url y lo guarda, quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
Enlaces encontrados: ['https://www.ejemplos.co/30-ejemplos-de-url/']
```

He revisado en varias ocasiones y no sé en que parte está mal mi código, ya que utilizo un ciclo While para poder iterar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A primera vista tu código se ve bien, pero te propongo una solución basada en generadores, que te simplificara la vida.

Una función *generadora* se asemeja a una función normal. La diferencia es que en lugar de hacer `return valor` haces un `yield valor`. El llamante recibe el valor, pero la función continua ejecutando, o sea, conserva su estado y puede producir una secuencia de valores.

```
def buscasig(pagweb):
    finposic = 0
    while True:
        iniciopos = pagweb.find('<a href=', finposic)
        if iniciopos == -1:
            break
        iniciocita = pagweb.find('"', iniciopos)
        finposic = pagweb.find('"', iniciocita + 1)
        url = pagweb[iniciocita + 1:finposic]
        yield url
```

Esta implementación tiene un `while` que cicla extrayendo una url de la página en cada pasada. Usamos el método `find()` con parámetro `start` para ir corriendo el punto de búsqueda dentro de `pagweb`.

Luego de extraer la url, la devuelve al llamante con `yield url`.

Cuando ya no hay más url, se termina el ciclo con un `break`. Como no hay más instrucciones en la función, esta termina.

#### Uso

Si llamas una función generadora lo que obtienes de vuelta es un *generador*, que lo puedes poner donde se requiera un iterable, típicamente en un `for` o comprensión de listas.

```
def main():
    with open('ejemplo.html') as archpagweb:
        pagweb = archpagweb.read()
        listaurls = [url for url in buscasig(pagweb)]
        print("Enlaces encontrados:", listaurls)
```

Con la página de Google produce

```
Enlaces encontrados: ['https://www.google.com/setprefs?sig=0_Ntel8TzoACL5N3ffTGoPwT1F1e8%3D&amp;hl=es-419&amp;source=homepage&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=0ahUKEwjKl8y8qoP7AhV_lJUCHYDEBtMQ2ZgBCBA', 'https://www.google.com/preferences?hl=en-CL&amp;fg=1', 'https://www.google.com/advanced_search?hl=en-CL&amp;fg=1', 'https://www.google.com/history/privacyadvisor/search/unauth?utm_source=googlemenu&amp;fg=1&amp;cctld=com', 'https://www.google.com/history/optout?hl=en-CL&amp;fg=1', 'https://support.google.com/websearch/?p=ws_results_help&amp;hl=en-CL&amp;fg=1']

Process finished with exit code 0
```